# How can I create time range grouping in window function SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm trying to create a grouping using multiple window function on SQL, the objective is to discern between different groups if there are  some other groups in the middle. see below table

```
Part |       time           |    expected result |
a    | 11-29-2022 00:05:00.000  |       1        |
a    | 11-29-2022 00:05:00.010  |       1        |
b    | 11-29-2022 00:06:00.000  |       2        |
c    | 11-29-2022 00:15:00.000  |       3        |
c    | 11-29-2022 00:15:00.000  |       3        |
b    | 11-29-2022 00:40:00.010  |       4        |
b    | 11-29-2022 00:40:00.020  |       4        |
b    | 11-29-2022 00:40:00.020  |       4        |
b    | 11-29-2022 00:40:00.030  |       4        |
```

I'm doing something like:

```
Select part, time, count(*) over(Partition by Part order by time )
```

Lets focus in part "b",  first occurrence  is at minute 6, after that appears different parts and part b appears again  at minute 40 so I need something like a time range to create the grouping

Also notice that sometimes the time is different in milliseconds even if the parts are consecutive (part b), those must belong to the same group.
Was trying to use the `Rank` window function but with 'range between'   wasn't able to get that result.

Thanks!

Comment: Please present your data in clean manner(select your table data and press ctrl+k. and also share your expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another option via dense_rank()

```
Select * 
      ,NewValue = dense_rank() over (order by convert(varchar(25),[Time],120))
 From YourTable
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: it gives me exactly what I ask, and probably if the time jump into an other minute in same grouping I will have an issue but I can round  that time to the nearest minute, so it will work,   thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this sql query.

```
Select part, time, dense_rank() over(Partition by Part )
```

or

```
Select part, time, dense_rank() over(Partition by Part order by time rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following  )
```

Comment: Hi! It does not acomplish because im not looking for a counter of records on each grouping, im looking for a kind of ID on each group.  if you see the table, the part C has only 2 rows but those rows has the number 3 because it was the third group.  Thanks!

Comment: @MaickGarcia.. corrected my solution based on your output